# Check if ALL elements in 2D-Array have same value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

if we have a 1D array, we could use the following to see if all elements are equal to 3:

```
int[] t = Enumerable.Repeat(3, 10).ToArray();

if (t.All(item => item.Equals(3))) MessageBox.Show("all elements equals to 3");
```

but if I have a 2D-array, how could I check if all elements are equal to 3 ( without any for-Loops ):

```
    int[,] t2D= new int[,] { { 3, 3 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 3 }, { 3, 3 } };

    if( CHECK IF ALL ELEMENTS IN **t2D** are equal to 3) 

               {
                MessageBox.Show("all elements equals to 3");
               }
```

What should I put in If-statement?

Comment: Without any for loops? ok... Considered that All() is using for loops? No need to be ashamed of for() or foreach()

Comment: @lboshuizen:  If you define a 2D array: 
 int[,] tt = new int[3, 4]; .All() is not part of the methods that you could use. Try tt.All => no method has been defined for 2D array case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2D-array is an [enumerable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw.aspx) (but it implements non-generic `IEnumerable`). And it's enumerator enumerates over all items in 2D-array. So, only thing you need to do - cast its items to `int` (thus retrieving `IEnumerable<int>`) and apply `All`

```
t2D.Cast<int>().All(x => x == 3)
```

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky: aw,thanks. just for the purpose of learning, how could I differentiate between non-generic Inumerable and generic Inumerables? or lets rephrase it: why generic types support .All() method or non-generic not?

Comment: @farzinparsa `All()` is an extension method on type `IEnumerable<T>` (defined in `Enumerable` class)or `IQueryable<T>`. Thats why only generic sequences support Linq methods.